# can't change postgres 10.4 user password on AWS ec2

Tags: linux, authentication, amazon-ec2, psql, postgresql-10

I want to add password protection to my psql db that I have set up on an Amazon Linux ec2 server. I only want the database to be accessible through the server instance(I am connecting to server via putty), and only with password authentication.

Previously, my pg_hba.conf (located at /var/lib/pgsql/data/) looked like this (USER: all, METHOD: trust):

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             postgres                                trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             postgres        ::1/128                 trust
# replication privilege.
local   replication     postgres                                trust
host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

To secure it, I've changed it to this (USER: postgres, METHOD: scram-sha-256):

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

To set password, I have used (to get into postgres terminal):

```
[ec2-user@AWS]: sudo -u postgres psql
```

Then i run:

```
postgres=# ALTER ROLE postgres PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

And i receive:

```
ALTER ROLE
```

Then when i exit the postgres terminal and change to postgres user with:

```
[ec2-user@AWS]: su - postgres
```

I am prompted to enter a password.
I enter the previously set:

```
Password: 'new_password'
```

And i get:

```
su: Authentification failure
```

What am I missing..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You habe to set `password_encryption` to `scram-sha-256` and reload the server before changing your password. `scram-sha-256` authentication only works with a `scram-sha-256`-hashed password.

Comment: ahh there we go - it's an open and shut case then. THANKS